# Trying to change the user Apache runs as and getting error when using sessions

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I have changed the user Apache runs under and am getting the following when trying to use sessions in PHP:

> Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_phbfugace53ngs8kt9pdgovf21, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0

I ran `chown myuser /var/lib/php/session` and still get the error. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, managed to sort this with `chown myuser /var/lib/php/session -R`

Comment: +1 for answering your own question